# How to solve Internal error in flutter to use firebase_auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using stable version of flutter and firebase_auth latest version but it give me error again and again

```
flutter: PlatformException(ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., null)
```

please help me to solve me this problem .
Thanks in advance…..

Comment: Did you end up solving it? I have it on iOS.

Answer (score 12):

If enabling Sign-in methods in Firebase console/Authentication didn't help you make sure your key is not restricted in Google Cloud Platform:

1. Go to [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com).
2. Open `APIs & Services` -> `Credentials` tab.

   [image]
3. Open your keys Android/iOS/Flutter.
4. Select "Don't restrict key" or carefully check APIs you want to enable.

   [image]

Comment: I was sure I'd set up my keys correctly so almost ignored this answer BUT it turns out that I had not enabled the 'Token Service API' on one of my keys in the Credentials tab of Google Cloud Platform.
I believe Firebase uses this to allow request new tokens for users when that users current token has expired, but doesn't give a very detailed error if it cannot access the Token Service API.
So to any future readers, please ensure that 'Token Service API' is enabled on any API-restricted keys.

Comment: Hey @Wes1324, I've enabled the Token Service API, but how can I make sure its connected to my keys?

Answer (score 10):

make sure your desired method is enabled in the firebase console eg. anonymous sign-in, email/pass sign-in.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that my simulator had cached a user from a different project (I have dev/prod firebase projects)

I had to log out and register again.

Hopefully, this saves someone as much head-scratching as I've just been through.

Comment: dude you're a life saver!
My issue was in IOS simulator. Had to uninstall the app to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Do also double-check the values in your GoogleService-Info.plist. I got this same error after using an incorrect API_KEY.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in my case, Flutter Fire was not configuring project correctly through cli.
There was a difference in Api keys written in *firebase_options.dart* file and the Api keys written in *google-service.json* and *GoogleService-Info.plist* files for iOS and Android Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget add `DynamicLink` the url which added in `Sign-in Domain` in `Authentication`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had Blocking Functions that verify users before account creation using beforeCreate().  I actually forgot I had it there and it was blocking all signups.

Wish the error message would be a bit more specific instead of internal error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

go to https://console.firebase.google.com/

choose your project;
click authentication -> get started;
choose email and password -> enable;

this worked for me

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34975548)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, in my case with Firebase Phone Auth, and the code didn't sent to some Carrier in my country and shown the same error.
You need to add another Auth method for users or try sending OTP by third party service.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same issue, but solved it when i noticed that the user has been logged in on the same device again