# Firebase Auth's method: sendSignInLinkToEmail gives an internal error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong. I'm trying to accomplish first step: 1. Send an authentication link to the user's email address (according to docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth)

- I have allowed this signin method

[image]

- I have whitelisted the URL:
  [image]

And this is my function:

```dart
@override
  Future<String> signInWithEmail(String email) async {
    var acs = ActionCodeSettings(
      // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
      // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
      url: 'https://myweb.app',// I'm using the real URL
      // This must be true
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOSBundleId: 'com.company.app', // I'm using the real iOSBundleId
      // androidPackageName: 'com.example.android',
      // installIfNotAvailable
      // androidInstallApp: true,
      // minimumVersion
      // androidMinimumVersion: '12'
    );
    // try {
    await logout();
    log('after logout: ${auth.currentUser}');
    return await auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email: email, actionCodeSettings: acs).then((value) {
      log('Successfully sent email verification');
      return 'Successfully sent email verification';
    }).catchError((e) {
      log('Error 21: ${e}');
      return 'Error sending email verification $e';
    });

    // throw UnimplementedError();
  }
```

Which gives me a very generic [firebase_auth/internal-error] An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.

although, there is no way to get more error details.

I've seen all the answers on similar questions ([How to solve Internal error in flutter to use firebase_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753050/how-to-solve-internal-error-in-flutter-to-use-firebase-auth)) and none of the answers helped.

I also must have well set up firebase_auth settings since I'm using google_signin in this app without any issue, so problems with GoogleService-Info.plist, etc. shall be discarded in my opinion.

I also reported the issue on [github](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11461)

===============================================================

UPDATE 2023-8-12: I can successfully reproduce the issue by following these steps:

1. start brand new Firebase project
   (Firebase automatically sets up all google cloud settings:)

[image]

3. start brand new flutter project
4. Configure Firebase for Flutter in CLI by following this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web
5. Allow signin in Firebase console like so:
   [image]
6. Whitelist the domain name by going to Authentification Settings authorized domains:
   [image]
7. Use this min repro code:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform).whenComplete(() {
    print("completedAppInitialize");
  });
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  Future signup() async {
    var acs = ActionCodeSettings(
      // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
      // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
      url: 'https://domain.app/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
      // This must be true
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOSBundleId: 'com.example.exp1',
      // androidPackageName: 'com.example.android',
      // installIfNotAvailable
      // androidInstallApp: true,
      // minimumVersion
      // androidMinimumVersion: '12'
    );

    var emailAuth = 'name@gmail.com';
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email: emailAuth, actionCodeSettings: acs)
        .catchError((onError) => print('Error sending email verification $onError'))
        .then((value) => print('Successfully sent email verification'));

    return;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    signup();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

7. This is console output:

```
flutter: completedAppInitialize
flutter: Error sending email verification [firebase_auth/internal-error] An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
flutter: Successfully sent email verification
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue but with the SMS auth, I created a ticket with firebase support so If I find anything that could help I'm gonna share it with you

Comment: Can you provide error details?

Comment: I wish I could provide error details. There is no way to do so. I tried every way I could think of. It seems Firebase doesn't provide that even though they themselves suggest looking for more detailed error. Weird!

Comment: did you go though this also ? [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#add_firebase_authentication_to_your_app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#add_firebase_authentication_to_your_app)  after going through https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web ?

Comment: It could also be related with very weird google thing where you have to go to google cloud services /apis and enable it on the project manually.. :S

Comment: That shouldn't be the case since Firebase automatically sets it up in Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: could you share `flutter doctor -v?` and your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Log in to the Firebase Console and navigate to the "Authentication" section. Look for  error or warning messages related to the authentication service. This might provide more details about the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that you didn't mention in your configuration is enabling Firebase Dynamic Links.

[Configuring Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth#configuring_firebase_dynamic_links)

*Firebase Auth uses Firebase Dynamic Links when sending a link that is meant to be opened in a mobile application. In order to use this feature, Dynamic Links need to be configured in the Firebase Console.*

This is is most likely the reason you get the cryptic error and I totally agree with you, it should be better handled in the `firebase_auth` package.

Once you enable the Dynamic Links - which are apparently [no longer supported and will stop working in 2025](https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq) - give it another try and check your Spam folder.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! First, since Firebase dynamic links are deprecated—I have no idea which service to use. Second, as far as I understand it, this comes in the play only once the email is sent. The problem is, the email is not even being sent.

Comment: I assume Google will add documentation on how to migrate away from Dynamic Links but for now you still have to use them even if they are deprecated. The email can't be sent because it depends on the dynamic links feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. I wouldn't think Google would rely on a feature they are deprecating. And on top of that putting a general error, not mentioning that it's missing the dynamic Links enabled.

Comment: From the Dynamic Links deprecation faq linked in the answer:
I only use Dynamic links for Firebase Authentication, will email link authentication in Firebase Authentication continue to work?
Yes, your email link authentication using Firebase Authentication will continue to work.

Firebase Authentication currently uses Firebase Dynamic Links to customize Authentication links, but we will provide an update to ensure that this functionality continues working after the Firebase Dynamic Links service is shut down.

Answer (score 0):

```
final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance; 

Future<User?> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password)async{

    UserCredential userCredential;
    try {
      userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return userCredential.user;

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      print(e.code);
      print(e.message);
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password)async{
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return userCredential.user;
  }
  

  String emailExample = "random@gmail.com";
  String passwordExample = "000000000"
    
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailExample, passwordExample);},
                  child: const Text('Sign-up'),
                ),
            TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailExample, passwordExample);},
                  child: const Text('Sign-in'),
                ),
          ]
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When you change your code as above, the login and registration processes will work. Also, if you add the firebase_auth: package to pubspec.yaml without writing any version, it will add the version that suits you.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for answers that use password-less option: `sendSignInLinkToEmail`

Comment: Future<User?> signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredentials =
      await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
      return userCredentials.user;
    } catch (_) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

Password-less option: You can use this code for signInAnonymously.