# flutter firebase authentication issue on IOS emulator - signInAnonymous [firebase_auth/internal-error]

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When implementing the anonymous SignIn by Firebase in my Flutter project (running on the IOS emulator) the terminal emitted the following error message:

> flutter: [firebase_auth/internal-error] An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.

Does someone know how this can me fixed or how I can get more detail?

This is the code for calling the signIn

```
Future<void> anonLogin() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

The option for anonymous sign in Firebase is enabled.

Comment: is your api key restricted for firebase apps?

Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753050/how-to-solve-internal-error-in-flutter-to-use-firebase-auth

Comment: No, there are no restrictions for any of the three API keys. But thanks for checking!

Comment: what about fingerprint in project settings of firebase?

Comment: This has helped with the android emulator, but the iOS one still emits the same error message

Comment: do you use flutterfire? it does all the necessary config... my guess is ios also has some setting config

Comment: Yes, I use flutter fire and just run an update, but this had no effect on the IOS emulation

Comment: Seeing as how android counterpart config mentioned in the docs here worked i suppose ios would too if you follow it.. This is for phone auth but ig its necessary.... worth a shot=> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth?hl=en&authuser=0

Comment: Also worth checking out is authorized domains and enabled dynamic links  as mentioned as answers here =>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843753/firebase-auths-method-sendsigninlinktoemail-gives-an-internal-error?rq=2

Comment: did you add bundle id for ios in credentials?